# Why are no results returned when performing a SOSL query on ContentNote in a Test Method?

Tags: apex, unit-test, sosl, contentnote

Following the example laid out in [Adding SOSL Queries to Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_SOSL.htm), I created a test method that inserts a ContentNote record, sets the results using Test.setFixedSearchResults(), and then performs a SOSL query.

```
@isTest 
static void sampleTestMethod(){
    ContentNote n = New ContentNote(
        Title='test',
        Content = Blob.valueof('test')
    );

    insert n;

    Id [] fixedSearchResults= new Id[1];
    fixedSearchResults[0] = n.Id;
    Test.setFixedSearchResults(fixedSearchResults);
    List<List<SObject>> searchList = [FIND 'test' 
                                      IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING 
                                      ContentNote(id, title)];

    system.assertEquals(1,searchList[0].size());
}
```

I expected that there would be one result record, however, the system.assertEquals fails, indicating that no results were returned.

This pattern for performing SOSL queries in test methods works as expected with other objects, but not with ContentNote.

In order to reproduce this [enhanced notes must be enabled](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=notes_admin_setup.htm&type=0&language=en_US&release=206.5) in your org.

Comment: +1 for a simple MVR. Have you tried setting `SeeAllData=true`?

Comment: SOSL performs 'text' search, whereas Content is stored as blob, though SOSL is not searching ContentNote

Comment: normally the SOSL query is in the code being tested, not in the testmethod. Does that make a difference?

Comment: @cropredy your point is valid, I have also checked that, through SOQL query in test class it returns the record and content is returning as Blob

Comment: I faced similar situation once and found that sosl queries don't run in test context. You need to manually populate your list as if it was returned from sosl query.

Comment: @AdrianLarson the test still fails if I set SeeAllData=true.

Comment: @SantanuBoral I understand that the content in the blob may not be searched, but I would still expect a result as the title of the note is "test" and the [documentation I linked to](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_SOSL.htm) indicates that once you set the results using Test.setFixedSearchResults() any result that isn't excluded by a WHERE or LIMIT clause should get returned.

Comment: @cropredy good question, but I have tried both ways, and both cause the same unexpected behavior. Originally my SOSL query was in the code being tested but I moved it into the test method so that I would have a concise example to post here.

Answer (score 2):

SOSL queries are tested similar to callouts using something like a Mock called `fixedSearchResults()`. See [Adding SOSL Queries to Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_SOSL.htm) in the Apex Docs. Here's an example from the docs on one way it can be used:

```
@isTest
private class SoslFixedResultsTest1 {

    public static testMethod void testSoslFixedResults() {
       Id [] fixedSearchResults= new Id[1];
       fixedSearchResults[0] = '001x0000003G89h';
       Test.setFixedSearchResults(fixedSearchResults);
       List<List<SObject>> searchList = [FIND 'test' 
                                         IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING 
                                            Account(id, name WHERE name = 'test' LIMIT 1)];
    }
}
```

Here's what you'll find in the [Test Class docs on setFixedSearchResults(setSearchResults)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_test.htm).

> setFixedSearchResults(setSearchResults)
>
> Defines a list of fixed search results to be returned by all
> subsequent SOSL statements in a test method. Signature
>
> public static Void setFixedSearchResults(ID[] setSearchResults)
>
> Parameters
>
> setSearchResults Type: ID[] The list of record IDs specified by
> opt_set_search_results replaces the results that would normally be
> returned by the SOSL queries if they were not subject to any WHERE or
> LIMIT clauses. If these clauses exist in the SOSL queries, they are
> applied to the list of fixed search results. Return Value
>
> Type: Void
>
> Usage
>
> If opt_set_search_results is not specified, all subsequent SOSL
> queries return no results.
>
> For more information, see Adding SOSL Queries to Unit Tests.

**EDIT:**

Having looked at the Object Reference for [Content Note](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentnote.htm), I suspect your issue may be in how you're creating the record in your test method. If you create the record as follows, I suspect your issue will disappear.

```
ContentNote n = new ContentNote();
n.Title = 'test';
String body = 'Hello World. Before insert/update, escape special characters such as ", ', &, and other standard escape characters.';
n.Content = Blob.valueOf(body.escapeHTML4());
insert(n);
```

Alternatively, it could be created like this:

```
ContentNote n = new ContentNote();
n.Title = 'test';
String body = '<b>Hello World. Because this text is already formatted as HTML, it does not need to be escaped. 
Special characters such as &quot;, etc. must already use their HTML equivalents.</b>';
n.Content = body;
insert(n);
```

If you add a `system.debug('content record id =  ' + n.Id )` to your test class, you may discover that you're not getting the record inserted properly as you might think.

Comment: I am familiar with the document you linked to, and I am using the fixedSearchResults() method to set the results. Despite this, no results are returned when the test method executes the SOSL query.

Comment: See my edited answer

Comment: I also didnt find the results from SOSL

Comment: @crmprogdev I tried the alternative methods you suggested for creating the ContentNote and the issue persisted. I also tried adding to my original sample code the debug statement as you suggested. The result was `USER_DEBUG|[154]|DEBUG|content record id =  06941000000k7adAAA` which seems to indicate that the ContentNote is being successfully inserted...

Comment: I have verified the same results. I've attempted several different things without success and am making some further inquiries. Will post an update should I learn anything helpful.